# How to calculate the sum of last inserted values in mongodb using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've a use case in which I've multiple devices who keep on inserting data to the mongodb. Till now, I've been calculating the most recently inserted value of each device using `deviceId` and comparing the data with given time period. If we select `monthly` with `deviceId`, it has to return the last 6 months data and the difference between present and last month's data. There may be situations to select one of these `weekly or quarterly`.

But I need to find the most recently inserted data of each device and need to calculate the sum and differences too at which am getting confused.

This is the sample code.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e0ae793b1384737a4f855cf",
    "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2019-02-25T09:25:37.059Z")
    "deviceId": "waterTest",
    "heat" : 20,
    "humidity" : 10
   },{
      "_id": "5e0ae7a2b1384737a4f855d0",
      "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2019-02-19T09:25:37.059Z")
      "deviceId": "waterTest",
      "heat" : 40,
      "humidity" : 20
   },{
      "_id": "5e0ae890b1384737a4f855d3",
      "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2020-01-19T09:25:37.059Z")
      "deviceId": "waterTest",
      "heat" : 60,
      "humidity" : 50
    },{
       "_id": "5e0af188981f39410cd89b73",
       "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2019-11-19T09:25:37.059Z")
       "deviceId": "Test",
       "heat": 60,
       "humidity": 50
   },{
      "_id": "5e0af196981f39410cd89b74",
      "entryDayTime" : ISODate("2019-12-19T09:25:37.059Z")
      "deviceId": "Test",
      "heat": 10,
      "humidity": 20
   }]
```

And the query for `quarterly` data is,

```
if(filter == "quarterly" && device!==undefined && payload.device){
            [err, avgValue] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(tempUniqueId)
                    .aggregate([
                        {
                            $match: {
                                "deviceId": payload.device
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $group:{
                                _id:{
                                    year: {$year: "$entryDayTime"},
                                    quarter: {
                                        $cond:[{
                                            $lte:[{$month:"$entryDayTime"},3]},"Q1",
                                                {$cond:[{$lte:[{$month:"$entryDayTime"},6]}, "Q2",
                                                    {$cond:[{$lte:[{$month:"$entryDayTime"},9]},"Q3","Q4"]}]}]
                                    }
                                },
                                value: aggreQuery
                            }
                        }
                    ]).toArray());
            if (err) {TE(err.message);}
        }
```

And the query for `monthly/weekly` data is,

```
if(payload.device!==undefined && payload.device && filter!=="quarterly"){
            [err, avgValue] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(tempUniqueId)
                    .aggregate([
                        {
                            $match: {
                                "deviceId": payload.device
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $group: {
                                _id: day,
                                value: aggreQuery
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $sort: { _id: -1 }
                        },
                        {
                            $project: { value: { '$divide': [{ '$trunc': { '$add': [{ '$multiply': ['$value', 100] }, 0.5] } }, 100] } }
                        }]).toArray());
            if (err) {TE(err.message);}
        }
```

I've already written some functionalities to compare the data with each month/quarter/week to check whether the data is available in the database or not. If the data is available, will return the data or else will return `0`.

The sample data would be,

```
"data": {
        "variables": [
            "heat"
        ],
        "lables": [
            "Feb-2020",
            "Jan-2020",
            "Dec-2019",
            "Nov-2019",
            "Oct-2019",
            "Sep-2019"
        ],
        "values": [
            [
                120,
                65,
                11,
                15,
                0,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "current": {
            "_id": "Feb-2020",
            "heat": 120
        },
        "previous": {
            "_id": "Jan-2020",
            "heat": 65
        },
        "difference": {
            "heat": 55
        }
    }
```

Now I need to get this kind of result for all devices and that too with most recently inserted record(last record) only.

Is it possible to get that in query level?
The devices are not in fixed numbers, might have one or more devices.
Or do I need to write any other function to get that?

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing.. So you just want to return the last inserted record for a given device?

Comment: No. Am now returning last value of a device. But I want the sum of last values of all devices.

Comment: as far as i understand your devices are sharing same db. You can make a collection for every device and put the ObjectIds into deviceId of your record collection. Then populate for all devices with your record collection.

Comment: All the devices are in same db and I'm able to populate the data. But the thing is, I need to get the sum of the last inserted values of every devices.